# Unable to retrieve all enabled Change Tracking Databases

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I'm trying to retrieve all Change Tracking databases by using:

```
Select * 
from sys.change_tracking_databases
```

I already enabled for all my databases, but the query only returns the current data which I'm using or return 0 row if I'm using master database.

What did I do wrong, or do I need to config anything else?

Answer (score 0):

This should work. And if it doesnt you havent done it correct

> You can also select properties on your database and go to Change Tracking option which is right below option field. There you can see if Change Tracking = True

```
SELECT d.name AS 'Database Name', t.*
FROM sys.change_tracking_databases t
INNER JOIN sys.databases d ON d.database_id = t.database_id
```

[image]

Comment: I already checked by UI, and they return Change Tracking true. But using the query doesn''t return correct result as I expected